# How to call double echo or double variable in php

Tags: php

I trying get another variable in php, from existing text but I have issue to do this.

When I `echo $address_number;` I get `list3`.

So I need to get variable `$list3` and I need `echo $list3;` after that.

Something like
`<?php  echo $(echo $address_number;); ?>`

But this is not possible. Any solutions?

Comment: [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Use variable variables like @Rizier123 told

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$address_number = $address.$number; 
$iframe_url ="$address_number"; 
<?php echo $$iframe_url; ?>
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Use variables variables and the way they work is like so

```
$adress_number = "list3";
$list3 = "some value";
echo $$address_number;
```

the above code will output 'some value', what it's doing is using the value of the variable $address_number and treating it as a variable name, so it will look for that variable name and print it's value